# Trouble loading Pickle file, Memory error

Tags: python, pickle

I want to load a pickle, and it worked in Python 2.7, but does not in Python 3.6
when loading it I get a memory error. I tried reformatted pickle to python 3 format, then tried to load it, but the problem persists,

The size of the pickle file is 1.1GB using Windows 10 laptop, 8GB of RAM. The pickle has 14804726 rows and 10 columns.

Any clue on how to further tackle this problem?

```
import pandas as pd

def readpickle(picklefile):
    rawdata = pd.read_pickle(picklefile)    
    return rawdata

picklefile=rawdata_py3.pkl' 
readpickle(picklefile)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-3fea1d423973>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts/pickletest.py', wdir='D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts')

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts/pickletest.py", line 11, in <module>
    readpickle(picklefile)

  File "D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts/pickletest.py", line 7, in readpickle
    rawdata = pd.read_pickle(picklefile) #to load pickle

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 180, in read_pickle
    return try_read(path, encoding='latin1')

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 175, in try_read
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 149, in read_wrapper
    return func(f)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 175, in <lambda>
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py", line 212, in load
    return up.load()

  File "c:\python36\lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File "c:\python36\lib\pickle.py", line 1077, in load_frame
    self._unframer.load_frame(frame_size)

  File "c:\python36\lib\pickle.py", line 257, in load_frame
    self.current_frame = io.BytesIO(self.file_read(frame_size))

MemoryError

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-3fea1d423973>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts/pickletest.py', wdir='D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts')

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts/pickletest.py", line 11, in <module>
    readpickle(picklefile)

  File "D:/PROJECTS/FR24/Scripts/pickletest.py", line 7, in readpickle
    rawdata = pd.read_pickle(picklefile) #to load pickle

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 180, in read_pickle
    return try_read(path, encoding='latin1')

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 175, in try_read
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 149, in read_wrapper
    return func(f)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 175, in <lambda>
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py", line 212, in load
    return up.load()

  File "c:\python36\lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File "c:\python36\lib\pickle.py", line 1077, in load_frame
    self._unframer.load_frame(frame_size)

  File "c:\python36\lib\pickle.py", line 257, in load_frame
    self.current_frame = io.BytesIO(self.file_read(frame_size))

MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I figured out what the issue was, it worked on python 2.7 but not python 3.6, when comparing these I noticed that python 3.6 was 32 bit and the python 2.7 version was 64 bit. So after uninstalling and reinstalling the 64 bit python 3.6 version the pickle loaded just fine.